# После преобразование в exe файл программа не открывается

Tags: python, база-данных, pyqt5, sqlite, exe

Писал программу в PyCharm, интерфейс с использованием PyQt. В виде py-файла программа работает, по после перевода в exe с помощью 'pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole main.py', выдаёт такую ошибку при открытии
[image: Сама ошибка]

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Все у вас открывается, просто в базе нет указанной таблицы. Нужно в коде предусмотреть создание таблиц, если их еще нет.

Comment: @insolor Но в базе данных есть таблица 'income' и ведь в виде файла с расширением .py всё работает. Или вы про что-то другое?

Comment: Если программа вам пишет, что в базе нет таблицы income, значит ее нет. Возможно у вас программа создает базу где-то в другом месте, не там где вы ожидаете, а таблицы не создает.

Comment: pyinstaller упаковывает код в архив и прикрепляет к интерпретатору. При запуске код распаковывается во временную папку и запускается, возможно база там же создается пустая.

Comment: @income в таком случае я совершенно не понимаю, что с этим делать, может, вы подскажете, как можно решить проблему?

Comment: У меня не такой ник, по чужим никам оповещения мне не приходят. Нужно смотреть код, как вы определяете путь к базе данных. Если никак не определяете, нужно, например, по sys.argv[0] брать путь к исполняемому файлу (в py виде там будет путь к интерпретатору, в exe виде - путь к вашему exe фалу), относительно него определять путь к базе.